# Use of select tag to display database in textbox PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Im trying to display my database value into the textbox using drop down menu. which is i did and it is displaying. the problem here is that when i choose an item in the drop down list, it goes back to the first choice or last choice, the explanation i got was, my loop is selecting all of the items in the field causing the drop down menu to go back to the first choice when i click on other items. can you help me with the code on how to stop going back to the first choice when i select other options. Here is my whole code. i also use functions.

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconnect.php');
include('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['brandname'])){
$id = $_POST['brandname'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstore WHERE brandname = '$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $price = $row['price'];
    $stocks = $row['stocks'];
}
}

?>

<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Choose here:</td>
                <td>

                    <select name = "brandname" onchange = "this.form.submit()">
                        <?php dropdown() ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $price ?>" disabled/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stocks:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="stocks" id="stocks" value="<?php echo $stocks ?>" disabled/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" disabled/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div align = "center">
    hi' <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
function dropdown(){
$all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstore");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($all)){

    echo "<option value = '".$row['brandname']."' selected='selected'>" .$row['brandname'] . "</option>";

   }
}
```

feel free to edit the whole code.. im a beginner in php and learning my way to it. thanks

Comment: do you need the selected='selected' in your loop? just means every single one will be selected

Comment: yes.. if i remove the select tag.. the first choice on the drop down menu is always being selected after i choose any option.. but if i include the select tag.. the last choice of the dropdown menu is always being selected after i choose other option.. and yes.. every single one of the option will be selected and that is exactly my problem.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Can add the multiple option if you need to select multiple

```
<select name="brandname" multiple>
   <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <?php
  do {  
  ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row['brandname']?>"> <?php echo $row['brandname'] ?></option>
 <?php
 } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($all));
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks.. uhmm.. where should i put this.? on functions.php or home.php ..? ill try it immediately..

Comment: but like they said in there demo, checkboxes would be the way to go if you are selecting multiple

Comment: yeah.. i read it carefully.. hahaha.. thanks man.. but i got this undefined variable "row" .. sorry .. completely noob here.. :)